# Weird interactions between setinterval, and classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, oop, velocity.js

Working on a slider, and Ive noticed that everything works great -

```
function Slider(element) {

    this.i = 0;

    this.element = element;

    var self = this;

    this.timer = window.setInterval(function() {
        switch (self.i) {
            case 0:
                $(element).velocity({ translateX: "-33.3333%" });
                self.i++;
            break;
            case 1:
                $(element).velocity({ translateX: "-66.6666%" });
                self.i++;
            break;
            case 2:
                $(element).velocity({ translateX: "0%" });
                self.i = 0;
            break;
        }
    }, 2000);
}

Slider.prototype.stop = function() {
    window.clearInterval(this.timer);
}

var i = 0;
$(".multi").each( function(){
    label = "label_" + i;
    window[label] = new Slider($(this));
    console.log(window[label]);
    console.log(label);
    console.log(i)
    i++;
});

$(".multi-nav a").click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    number = $(this).parent().attr("class").split(" ").pop();
    label = "label_" + number;
    console.log(label)
    console.log(window[label]);
    window[label].stop();
});
```

Demo - http://codepen.io/JordanDWhalen/pen/QjGNYm

Until I add in animations for  toggling classes on the targets of the events that stop the interval:

```
function Slider(element) {

    this.i = 0;

    this.element = element;

    var self = this;

    this.timer = window.setInterval(function() {
        switch (self.i) {
            case 0:
                $(element).velocity({ translateX: "-33.3333%" });
                $(".multi-nav a").velocity({ opacity: ".5" });
                $(".multi-nav ." + self.i).velocity({ opacity: "1" });
                self.i++;
            break;
            case 1:
                $(element).velocity({ translateX: "-66.6666%" });
                $(".multi-nav a").velocity({ opacity: ".5" });
                $(".multi-nav ." + self.i).velocity({ opacity: "1" });
                self.i++;
            break;
            case 2:
                $(element).velocity({ translateX: "0%" });
                $(".multi-nav a").velocity({ opacity: ".5" });
                $(".multi-nav ." + self.i).velocity({ opacity: "1" });
                self.i = 0;
            break;
        }
    }, 2000);
}

Slider.prototype.stop = function() {
    window.clearInterval(this.timer);
}

var i = 0;
$(".multi").each( function(){
    label = "label_" + i;
    window[label] = new Slider($(this));
    console.log(window[label]);
    console.log(label);
    console.log(i)
    i++;
});

$(".multi-nav a").click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    number = $(this).parent().attr("class").split(" ").pop();
    label = "label_" + number;
    console.log(label)
    console.log(window[label]);
    window[label].stop();
});
```

Demo - http://codepen.io/JordanDWhalen/pen/RWoaYR

Comment: You should be using `.data` to attach the slider instance to a link element, not the "last classname" plus numbered global `window` properties

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was an issue with the animations being fired at too many matching elements. As a result, both intervals needed to be interrupted, before either would stop animating.

```
var sliderId = 0;
function Slider(element) {

    this.id = sliderId;
    sliderId++;

    this.i = 0;

    this.element = element;

    var self = this;

    this.timer = window.setInterval(function() {
        switch (self.i) {
            case 0:
                $(element).velocity({ translateX: "-33.3333%" },{delay: 1500, duration: 500 });
                $(".multi-nav." + self.id + " .active" ).removeClass("active");
                $(".multi-nav." + self.id + " ." + self.i).addClass("active");
                self.i++;
            break;
            case 1:
                $(element).velocity({ translateX: "-66.6666%" }, { delay: 1500, duration: 500 });
                $(".multi-nav." + self.id + " .active" ).removeClass("active");
                $(".multi-nav." + self.id + " ." + self.i ).addClass("active");
                self.i++;
            break;
            case 2:
                $(element).velocity({ translateX: "0%" }, {delay: 1500, duration: 500 });
                $(".multi-nav." + self.id + " .active" ).removeClass("active");
                $(".multi-nav." + self.id + " ." + self.i ).addClass("active");
                self.i = 0;
            break;
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Adding in the .id to the object, and then utilizing that within my animations fixed the issue!

Comment: `".multi-nav." + self.id` will try to match the ID as a class. How can that work?

Comment: Maybe your answer would make sense if you included the HTML in the question.

Comment: Why don't you just use `$(self).find(".active")` and `$(self).find("."+self.i)`

Comment: "self.id" is equivalent to the class that I have set on insert of a new div with a multi class or a new div with a .multi-nav class, its also given a number assigned as a class, starting at zero, and iterating for each one it finds. So this ends up targeting just the HTML that's linked to that id/class. If you look at the HTML on the codepens that I linked, it might make more sense.

Comment: Anything important for understanding the question should be in the question, not at an external site. Please copy the relevant parts of the HTML from the codepen to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you ...

- invoke `Slider()` on the ".multi-wrap" wrappers, not the ".multi" elements
- find the ".multi" and ".multi-nav" elements within each wrapper
- attach the stop functionality in the `Slider()` function rather than having a `.stop()` method,

... you will find that :

- the need for `this.xxx`, properties disappears in favour of private vars
- the need for globals disappears
- the need for `new` disappears and invokation becomes much simpler.

You might end up with something like this :

```
function Slider(index, wrapper) {
    var i = 0;
    var $multi = $(wrapper).find(".multi");
    var $multiNav = $multi.siblings(".multi-nav");
    var timer = window.setInterval(function() {
        $multi.velocity({ translateX: ['-33.3333%', '-66.6666%', '0%'][i] });
        $multiNav.velocity({ opacity: '1' });
        $multiNav.find("a").velocity({ opacity: '.5' });
        i = (i + 1) % 3;
    }, 2000);
    $multiNav.find("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.clearInterval(timer);
    });
}
$(".multi-wrap").each(Slider);
```